# Naviagtion Controller not working after chnaging main storyboard in Scene delegate

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have deleted the main.storyboard from my project and changed the initial screen to Home.storyboard using scenedelegate.swift file. Now when I try to Navigation controller, it is nil.

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }        
window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)        
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "VerifyOTP", bundle: nil)        
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "VerifyOTP")        window?.rootViewController = initialViewController        
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**HomeVC.swift**

```
let OrderScreen: PlaceOrderVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlaceOrder") as! PlaceOrderVC            
let navigationController = self.navigationController!            
print(navigationController)            
OrderScreen.BillDisplay = self.billing            
navigationController.pushViewController(OrderScreen, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed your `initialViewController` in navigation controller and then make the `navController` the `rootViewController`. Check the code below.

```
    guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "VerifyOTP", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "VerifyOTP")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: If I need to add tab bar controller, do I have to use pushViewController instead of rootviewController = navController.